# pdfmake generate error when array is more than one

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using `pdfmake` to generate PDF in my application. What I've noticed is, if its generating a pdf with one array it works fine, but fails if it's more than one. I get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_calcWidth' of undefined
```

Code

```
  createPdf() {
    let original = [
      {id:1, category: 'Food', amount: '40', Date: '2021-01-01'},
      {id:2, category: 'Transport', amount: '10', Date: '2021-01-03'},
      {id:3, category: 'Bill Payment', amount: '40', Date: '2021-01-01'}
  ]

  let another = []
   original.forEach(item => {
    another.push(item.id.toString(), item.category.toString(), item.amount.toString())
  })
  console.log(another)



    var docDefinition = {
      content: [
        {
          table: {
            headerRows: 1,
            widths: [ '*', 'auto', 100, '*', 'auto' ],
    
            body: [
              [ 'ID', 'Category', 'Amount', 'Date', 'Description' ],
              another
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    };

    this.pdf = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
    this.downloadPDF()

  }

  downloadPDF() {
    this.pdf.download();
  }
```